# How can I get files by javascript and post send for ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have this form in html for multiple file uploading .

```
<form class="userform" method="post" action="upload.php" role="form"   enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        <input  name="title" type="text" ><br/>
        <input  type="file" name="media[]" >
        <div class="filesupload">
          <input type="file" name="media[]" >
        </div>
<script>
 $(document).on("click",".add-new-file",function()
            {
                $('.filesupload').append('<input  name="media[]" type="file"  >');
            });
</script>
</form>
```

I will get input files by javascript and send to upload.php for uploading. but I don't know how to get files values in javascript.

Comment: What do you mean by "files values"? Do you want the file name, size, or content?

Comment: ok! I will get files by $_FILES["media"] in upload.php but I don't Know how to send by $(ajax)

Comment: you might need to read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications#Example.3A_Uploading_a_user-selected_file first. Also its possible only with browsers that support xhr2 http://caniuse.com/#feat=xhr2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you using HTML5

```
   var fileList = document.getElementById("yourInput").files;
    for(var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
        //Do something with individual files
    }
```

Using jquery

```
$("input[name=file1]").change(function() {
    var names = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < $(this).get(0).files.length; ++i) {
        names.push($(this).get(0).files[i].name);
    }
    $("input[name=file]").val(names);
});​
```